# when autowired value injected in Spring

Tags: spring, annotations, inversion-of-control, code-injection, autowired

Does any one know when exactly the autowired filed (if there is no difference to via constructor or set method) value injected to the class where it is used?

For example, I am trying to inject the value serverProperties. As I can find, the field has not got the value injected by the time I am trying to using it set the initial value for class field ROOT_DIRECTORY, where serverProperties throws Null pointer exception. When the injection actually happens? After all class fields initialised? Thanks in advance.

PS:The holding bean is an annotated controller.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("serverProperties")
private Properties serverProperties;

private final String ROOT_DIRECTORY = serverProperties.getProperty("root.path");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bean is

1. created (using constructor, factory method, etc.)
2. dependencies are injected (your `@Autowired` properties is set)
3. [init methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean) are called

It is in this third step when you need to set `ROOT_DIRECTORY`, and not just define it in the class body. So your code should look like

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("serverProperties")
private Properties serverProperties;

private String ROOT_DIRECTORY;

public void init() {
    ROOT_DIRECTORY = serverProperties.getProperty("root.path");
}
```

and your bean should have a defined `init` method like

```
<bean id="exampleInitBean" class="examples.ExampleBean" init-method="init"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, my bean is actually a annotated controller, which means I can't use init-method="init". An alternative?

Comment: I think I have found it 
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   // ...
}

Answer (score 2):

if you are using annotation, you can use @PostConstruct